# How to group selectItems in selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I would like to use the example from the primefaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) to group selectItems in selectOneMenu:

```
<h:outputText value="Grouping: " />  
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{formBean.car}">  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
        <f:selectItems value="#{formBean.cars}" />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

My problem is, that there is no implementation of the bean. Now I don't know, how to implement the grouping of the selectItems inside the method getCars(). And I can't find any other example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The source code of the showcase's `#{formBean}` is available [here](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/view/FormBean.java). Here's an extract of relevance:

```
private List<SelectItem> cars;

public FormBean() {
    SelectItemGroup g1 = new SelectItemGroup("German Cars");
    g1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] {new SelectItem("BMW", "BMW"), new SelectItem("Mercedes", "Mercedes"), new SelectItem("Volkswagen", "Volkswagen")});

    SelectItemGroup g2 = new SelectItemGroup("American Cars");
    g2.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] {new SelectItem("Chrysler", "Chrysler"), new SelectItem("GM", "GM"), new SelectItem("Ford", "Ford")});

    cars = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    cars.add(g1);
    cars.add(g2);
}
```

Thus, your missing key is [`SelectItemGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItemGroup.html).

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) - "Dynamic list with groups"

Comment: Can a SelectItemGroup have other SelectItemGroups within?

Answer (score 2):

In this example `getCars()` returns a list of `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` objects. There is one subclass of this class, named `SelectItemGroup` which represent a grup in `selectOneMenu`. Value field of this object is ignored and just label is used. So in your list you can mix `SelectItem` and `SelectItemGroup` objects to organize your list in groups. Note, that `SelectItem` objects which are part of group are present as array in `SelectItemGroup` object. You can set that array through constructor or setter (`setSelectItems()`).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know SelectItemGroup.