# Is it possible to create SelectOneMenu with different SelectItem types

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to create a SelectOneMenu which would embrace two different value types - Account and Card, so that in the result I will get something like this in a single drop-down list:

Cards:
-1224455667778822
-5353534344344343
Accounts:
-2323323232
-2323233211

I think that some kind of abstraction may be necessary in order to define its value type in the value attribute of SelectOneMenu, but I can't imagine how I would get the concrete type that has been selected.

Any help would be apppreciated.

@Update
As a temporary workaround I used String instead of Card and Account object. Parsing them to the necessary object depending on the number of digits(cards have 16 digits, accounts 14).

Answer (score 0):

Tiana you could probably use the Grouping example that is demonstrated here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is kind of a duplicate question. But, just for reference you could easily look at the following code explained by **@BalusC** or also look at the Primefaces example of SelectOneMenu Grouping.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14627849/3403415

Hope it helps!!

Comment: If you think it is a duplicate please Mark It is such

Comment: Can't do it as I don't have enuf reputation points. **Oops!!**

Comment: Well, the problem was not how to group those items, rather than how to get the necessary value out of it depending on the concrete type. So, I created an interface which both of these entities implement and  used a converter to get the necessary type out of it.

Comment: @Kukeltje Could you please review this question and mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: I voted to close... Don't have enough reputation to directly close...